# Use tag synonym in page title generation algorithm

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, title, localization

Most of SE question pages from main sites (not metas) have an HTML title (string inside `<TITLE>` tag) with the following form

```
primary tag - question's title - site name
```

But there are some exceptions. As far as I see the page title of the question doesn't include primary tag from the question if question's title already has that tag as a string.

For instance: [Не запускается программа после компиляции. Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1227474/176217). Page title is:

```
Не запускается программа после компиляции. Python - Stack Overflow на русском
```

Because "Python" is used in the title as well as a primary tag for the question.

At the same time tag synonyms are not participated in that scheme. E.g. [Нужна помощь с текстовыми данными с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1228008/176217) has a following page title:

```
c++ - Нужна помощь с текстовыми данными с++ - Stack Overflow на русском
```

Since the question title contains a Cyrillic "с" with pluses instead of Latin "c" with pluses. Primary tag includes Latin letter, but there is [synonym](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/synonyms) with Cyrillic one. Visually page title contains primary tag twice. Of course this is specific case and in other situations tag synonyms look very different from the primary tag, but since they are already synonyms they should be used interchangeably.

So my proposal here is also take tag synonyms into account when generating the page title.